# Wait for Bash process substitution subshells

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, process-substitution

I pipe the same content to multiple commands with `tee`, redirects and process substitution subshells like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'hello' | tee \
  >( sleep 3; cat /dev/stdin ) \
  >( sleep 2; cat /dev/stdin ) \
  >( sleep 1; cat /dev/stdin )

wait # Doesn't work :(
```

However, what I see is that the process substitution subshell output is written to the terminal after the main script exits and `wait` doesn't work:

```
$ ./test.sh
hello
$ hello
hello
hello
```

How to properly wait for the process substitution subshells?

Comment: I *think* this isn't possible. You'd need to capture the PIDs of each subshell, but process substitution will never give them to you. I will be fascinated to see if there is a simple solution though.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Apparently `zsh` is `wait`-ing for the children...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash`, you can't wait for process substitution. In:

```
cmd1 > >(cmd2)
```

the whole command finish as soon as `cmd1` finish, regardless the status of `cmd2`.

You have to implement a mechanism to signal the parent process that the `cmd2` have finished. An easy way, using a fifo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'rm wait.fifo' EXIT
mkfifo wait.fifo

echo 'hello' | tee \
  >( sleep 3; cat /dev/stdin; : >wait.fifo ) \
  >( sleep 2; cat /dev/stdin; : >wait.fifo ) \
  >( sleep 1; cat /dev/stdin; : >wait.fifo )

for (( i=0;i<3;i++ )); do read <wait.fifo; done
```

Comment: Works indeed, thanks! Although I ended up writing to a file and starting the commands separately.