# Why I need to type press Enter key to finish this command?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdin, process-substitution

I'm a new Linux user and I was doing some experiments and trying to understand *Process Substitution*. I believe I already have a basic understanding of it. But here is a case that I don't know why. I'm using Bash on Ubuntu 20.04.

`echo hi` just sends the string `hi` with a newline character to stdout.

```
root@u2004:~# echo hi | od -a
0000000   h   i  nl
0000003
root@u2004:~#
```

`cat` can read from the pipeline as its stdin, and send what it read down to the pipeline.

```
root@u2004:~# echo hi | cat
hi
root@u2004:~# echo hi | cat | od -a
0000000   h   i  nl
0000003
root@u2004:~#
```

As I understand, the command `echo hi > >(cat)` will also make `cat` read from its stdin (and print to the console). But when I run it, I got this:

```
root@u2004:~# echo hi > >(cat)
root@u2004:~# hi
<the cursor blinks at this location>
```

I have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to finish the command.

```
root@u2004:~# echo hi > >(cat)
root@u2004:~# hi
Enter
root@u2004:~#
```

Why this behavior? Is my understanding of the command `echo hi > >(cat)` correct?

Comment: I didn't reproduced after many tries, but finally made it with `echo hi > >(sleep 1; cat)`. I guess the race was not fair on my box.

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403783/the-process-substitution-output-is-out-of-the-order and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351780/wait-for-bash-process-substitution-subshells

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, the command completed successfully.

What you saw:

```
root@u2004:~# echo hi > >(cat)
root@u2004:~# hi
<the cursor blinks at this location>
```

You entered the command, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your shell printed out your prompt, and then the `cat` process, launched asynchronously, completes and spits out `hi\n`.

The cursor blinking on the blank line belongs to the prompt on the previous line, but the newline from the `echo` command has disrupted your display.

The subsequent "hitting enter" just gives you a new prompt. If you enter a command and hit enter, that command will run.